# Comparison of atom libraries for Haskell, e.g. simple-atom and stringtable-atom

Tags: haskell

I find myself needing a string table in a Haskell program I'm developing. In particular, I want a system which allows be to box any String into (say) an 'Atom'; given an Atom, you should be able to recover the original string it came from, and (critically) comparing two Atoms for equality should be as fast (or almost as fast) as a pointer compare.

(One can easily devise a referentially-transparent interface for this functionality; the implementation will use `unsafePerformIO` internally but the user of the library need not know about such details.)

Two libraries available on Hackage seem to be in the right ballpark: stringtable-atom and simple-atom. Does anyone have any experience using these libraries? In particular, are there any suggestions as to what the benefits of one over the other might be?

Comment: If you plan to use this with any kind of multi-threading I'd be suspicious of both those packages.  The stringtable-atom package uses C code that need to execute atomically.  The simple-atom package uses `atomicmodifyIORef`, but performs evaluation inside the atomic function that could invoke the `insert` function again.  This is not good.  Writing a thread-safe atom module has to be done with great care.

Comment: @augustss. Indeed! This is a big reason why I'm looking for an off the shelf package rather than rolling my own. (Indeed, my hyper caution on this score is partly prompted by your great blog post on memoization a while back :) )

Comment: Perhaps I'll upload another atom package.

Comment: Wow! That would be very kind, although it's really not necessary---I can try to roll my own, although doubtless my efforts would not be as good as those of a Master such as yourself :-). If you are thinking of doing an implementation, it strikes me that ideally one could solve the problem for more than just strings; depending on the implementation route, you probably ought to be able to `Atomize' any type with Eq and Cmp or with Eq and a hash function.

Comment: I already have an implementation, but it needs a little cleaning up and tuning.

Comment: I haven't stress-tested `simple-atom` yet, so I wouldn't advise you to use it in a multi-threaded environment, yet, so there may well be issues.  If augustss's code is battle-tested, then that would certainly be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another nice choice would be ekmett's new intern package, which handles bytestrings as well as more complex recursive types: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intern

He has assured me it is threadsafe.

Comment: The implementation of intern uses (a) weak references and (b) unsafeDupableIO.  (a) may slow down the GC if you have many of them.  Regarding (b) I'd love to see a comment in the code describing why it's safe.  (Using unsafePerfomIO + NOINLINE would certainly be safer, yet slower.)

Comment: @nominolo: I believe the purpose of the weak references is to ensure that strings are de-interned if they are no longer visible. For at least some applications, this is an important feature; and it cannot be implemented without the weakRefs. In other applications, it may be wasteful overhead---another reason that the variety of libraries and options is helpful.

Comment: @nominolo: Regarding your point (b), do you happen to know of a good guide that tells you exactly what you need to make sure to ensure that unsafePerformIO is safe? Why/when are NOINLINEs needed to ensure referential transparency/safety?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [monad-atom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-atom) for my own use. It's not what you want if you need globally unique atoms, but if all you need is a string table it is simple and safe.